# Send raw infrared codes on Sony Xperia devices

Tags: api, sony, infrared

i have posted this hoping that a responsible sony engineer answers like recommended on https://developer.sony.com/support/how-to-post-tag-a-question/

My question/requirement is simple.. *Why* do Sony devices like the Xperia Z2 tablet not implement the Google Infrared API:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/ConsumerIrManager.html

I think the official Sony IR Remote API is a ridiculous choice compared to that. Not only it cannot send raw infrared sequences, but also limits its use to Sony STOCK roms. I think this is a major flaw and limits the possibilities of Sony devices compared to other brands like Samsung and HTC.

The Sony API description says:

"Sony’s remote control app on the tablet or smartphone, through the IR remote API, without the need for low level communication with the infrared element."

It sounds like something positive - while it is in fact negative. I WANT the low-level communication!!! So please do something, releasing some code snippet how to access the blaster and send raw commands like 400µs on, 600µs off would be enough , and would open sony devices to third party infrared apps which can support more devices, and open new possibilities. Shouldn't be so hard.

Comment: You are right, I have the same problem. Sony IR is useless for all and is not compliant with Google Android directives.

Answer (score 0):

Devices such as the Z2 Tablet and older predate the Google IR API that was introduced in Android 4.4.  As such, the hardware was not designed to support the Google IR API and can only support the Sony IR API.

Comment: Even if this is true, then add some sendRaw() code method into Sony IR API like LG did with their api - Also Kitkat was available before the release of some devices which do not support the Google IR API. See in this link: http://developer.lge.com/MOBILE_HELP/topic/lge.mobilesdk.LGQRemote.api/html/Developing/Developing/Sending%20Raw%20IR%20Data.htm   , LG also uses UEI like SONY. So it IS possible somehow to make it support IR-Data ;) Please do us this favor

Comment: Time has passed still no solution. Can't you just give us a code-snippet on how to send raw infrared codes? There must be a way to access the blaster without a full-blown SDK. In your app you do this too.. Why only Sony with this strange way, All other manufactuers just use the Google-API